# Double move when returned by value C++

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Hello for the sake of learning c++ i am building my own string class, and have a question regarding returning by value.

```
MTX::String MTX::String::operator+(String& sObject)
{

    //Calculate the size of a buffer we will need
    int _cBufferSizeTmp = (_cBufferSize - 1) + sObject._cBufferSize;

    //Now create a buffer which can hold both of the objects
    char* _cBufferTmp = new char[_cBufferSizeTmp];

    //Now copy first string in to it, but without the terminator
    Memory::Copy((void*)_cBuffer, _cBufferTmp, _cBufferSize - 1);

    //Copy second string but with null terminator
    //Now that takes into account the offset of a second string to copy (void *)(_cBufferTmp + (_cBufferSize - 1))
    Memory::Copy((void*)sObject._cBuffer, (void *)(_cBufferTmp + (_cBufferSize - 1)), sObject._cBufferSize);

    //And now we construct our tmp string with it
    String _tmpString;
    _tmpString._cBuffer = _cBufferTmp;
    _tmpString._cBufferSize = _cBufferSizeTmp;

    return _tmpString;
}
```

The question is, when the value is returned it is moved in to temporary object via move constructor, and then this temporary object is again moved to another object according tot his scheme

```
int main() {
    
    MTX::String Greetings;

    MTX::String tst1 = "Hello World";
    MTX::String tst2 = "! And good bye\n";
    
    Greetings = tst1 + tst2;
    std::cout << Greetings.sBuffer();  //Didnt implement ostream stuff yet

    return 0;
}
```

So here is console output

```
Created an empty string object
Created a string object "Hello World"
Created a string object "! And good bye
"
Created an empty string object
Created (Move) a string object "Hello World! And good bye //Here it creates a new tmp object and moves previous tmp in to it
"
deleting a string object
moved a string object via =
deleting a string object
Hello World! And good bye
deleting a string object
deleting a string object
deleting a string object
```

Why does it first move it into another tmp object before actually assigning it to the Greetings object.

Here is the full source code of string.cpp

```
#include "String.h"
#include "Memory.h"

//Work better on utils
int MTX::String::Length(const char *cBuffer) {
    int count = 0;
    while (cBuffer[count] != '\0') {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

char* MTX::String::sBuffer()
{
    return _cBuffer;
}

MTX::String& MTX::String::operator=(String& sObject) 
{
    std::cout << "Copied a string bject via =\n";
    return (String&) Buffer<char>::operator=((String&) sObject);
}

MTX::String& MTX::String::operator=(String&& sObject) noexcept 
{
    std::cout << "moved a string object via = \n";
    return (String&) Buffer<char>::operator=((String&&) sObject);
}

MTX::String& MTX::String::operator=(const char* cBuffer)
{
    Clear();

    //Get Length of a buffer with String::Length();
    int cBufferSize = String::Length(cBuffer) + 1;

    //Create a buffer
    _cBuffer = new char[cBufferSize];
    _cBufferSize = cBufferSize;

    //Copy contents of a buffer to local buffer
    Memory::Copy((void*)cBuffer, (void*)_cBuffer, _cBufferSize);

    return *this;
}

MTX::String MTX::String::operator+(String& sObject)
{

    //Calculate the size of a buffer we will need
    int _cBufferSizeTmp = (_cBufferSize - 1) + sObject._cBufferSize;

    //Now create a buffer which can hold both of the objects
    char* _cBufferTmp = new char[_cBufferSizeTmp];

    //Now copy first string in to it, but without the terminator
    Memory::Copy((void*)_cBuffer, _cBufferTmp, _cBufferSize - 1);

    //Copy second string but with null terminator
    //Now that takes into account the offset of a second string to copy (void *)(_cBufferTmp + (_cBufferSize - 1))
    Memory::Copy((void*)sObject._cBuffer, (void *)(_cBufferTmp + (_cBufferSize - 1)), sObject._cBufferSize);

    //And now we construct our tmp string with it
    String _tmpString;
    _tmpString._cBuffer = _cBufferTmp;
    _tmpString._cBufferSize = _cBufferSizeTmp;

    return _tmpString;
}

MTX::String MTX::String::operator+(const char* pBuffer)
{

    //Calculate the size of a buffer we will need
    int _cBufferSizeTmp = (_cBufferSize - 1) + String::Length(pBuffer) + 1;

    //Now create a buffer which can hold both of the objects
    char* _cBufferTmp = new char[_cBufferSizeTmp];

    //Now copy first string in to it, but without the terminator
    Memory::Copy((void*)_cBuffer, _cBufferTmp, _cBufferSize - 1);

    //Copy second string but with null terminator
    //Now that takes into account the offset of a second string to copy (void *)(_cBufferTmp + (_cBufferSize - 1))
    Memory::Copy((void*)pBuffer, (void*)(_cBufferTmp + (_cBufferSize - 1)), String::Length(pBuffer) +1);

    //And now we construct our tmp string with it
    String _tmpString;
    _tmpString._cBuffer = _cBufferTmp;
    _tmpString._cBufferSize = _cBufferSizeTmp;

    //no need to delete the tmp buffer, cause ownership was taken away from it.

    //And return it by value cause it is gona get deleted anyway
    return _tmpString;
}

MTX::String MTX::String::operator<<(String& sObject) noexcept
{
    return *this + sObject;
}

MTX::String MTX::operator<<(MTX::String sObjectSelf, MTX::String sObject) {
    return sObjectSelf + sObject;
}
```

Here is the base class

```
//Constructor Default
        Buffer() : _cBuffer(nullptr), _cBufferSize(0) {};

        Buffer(T* pBuffer, int len) {


            //Check if pBuffer is not nullptr
            if (pBuffer != nullptr) {
                //Allocate the memory needed for a buffer
                _cBuffer = new T[len];
                _cBufferSize = len;
                //Now copy contents of a buffer 
                Memory::Copy((void*)pBuffer, (void*)_cBuffer, sizeof(T) * len);
            }
            else {
                _cBuffer = nullptr;
                _cBufferSize = 0;
            }
        };

        Buffer(Buffer& Object)
        {

            //If attempted to clone empty buffer
            if (Object._cBuffer != nullptr) {
                //Create new buffer with a size of a source buffer
                _cBuffer = new T[Object._cBufferSize];
                _cBufferSize = Object._cBufferSize;

                //Copy contents of that buffer in to local
                Memory::Copy((void*)Object._cBuffer, (void*)_cBuffer, _cBufferSize);
            }
            else {
                _cBuffer = nullptr;
                _cBufferSize = 0;
            }

        };

        Buffer(Buffer&& Object) {

            // If attempting to move empty buffer
            if (Object._cBuffer != nullptr) {

                //Take ownership of buffer
                _cBuffer = Object._cBuffer;
                Object._cBuffer = nullptr;

                //Set buffer size
                _cBufferSize = Object._cBufferSize;
                Object._cBufferSize = 0;

            }
            else {
                _cBuffer = nullptr;
                _cBufferSize = 0;
            }
        };

        Buffer& operator=(Buffer& Object) {

            //Clear buffer, cause it is going to be cleaned anyway
            Clear();

            //If attempted to clone empty buffer
            if (Object._cBuffer != nullptr) {

                //Create new buffer with a size of a source buffer
                _cBuffer = new T[Object._cBufferSize];
                _cBufferSize = Object._cBufferSize;

                //Copy contents of that buffer in to local
                Memory::Copy((void*)Object._cBuffer, (void*)_cBuffer, _cBufferSize);
            }

            return *this;
        };

        Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& Object) {

            //Same as copy assign, buffer is going to be cleared anyway
            Clear();

            // If attempting to move empty string
            if (Object._cBuffer != nullptr) {

                //Take ownership of buffer
                _cBuffer = Object._cBuffer;
                Object._cBuffer = nullptr;

                //Set buffer size
                _cBufferSize = Object._cBufferSize;
                Object._cBufferSize = 0;

            }

            return *this;
        };
```

And string constructors

```
//Constructors
        String() 
            :Buffer() {

                        std::cout << "Created an empty string object\n";
    
        };

        String(const char* cBuffer)
            :MTX::Buffer<char>((char*)cBuffer, String::Length(cBuffer) + 1) {
            
                        std::cout << "Created a string object"<<" \""<<cBuffer<<"\"\n";
            
        };

        String(String& sObject)
            :MTX::Buffer<char>((String&)sObject) {

                        std::cout << "Created (Copy) a string object" << " \"" << sObject._cBuffer << "\"\n";
            
        };

        String(String&& sObject) noexcept
            :Buffer<char>((String&&)sObject) {
            
                        std::cout << "Created (Move) a string object" << " \"" << _cBuffer << "\"\n";

        };

        ~String() {
        
        
                        std::cout << "deleting a string object\n";
        
            
        }
```

Comment: I think to properly address/answer this question, we will need to see the declaration of your `MTX` class - and the *definitions* (if any) of its move constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: You can reduce the code to remove the member functions that aren't used in the other code you've posted.

Comment: @AdrianMole this is a derived class, do you want me to post just the string class or it is base too ?

Comment: I think we'll need the move, copy, assignment and destructor. Of the base if they aren't in the derived.

Comment: @AdrianMole Posted

Comment: Reducing this to a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Do you compile with optimizations enabled? Does the answer change if you do? The move from `_tmpString` to the return value may be optimized away by NRVO, but is not mandated to be.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yeah NRVO is the answer, wanted to get more insights why it doesn't do it without any optimizations, or what is the mechanic behind it, my idea is that without any optimizations it will just create this tmp object despite the fact i am already using tmp object

Comment: You are not using a tmp object. Despite `tmp` in its name, `_tmpString` is a named object, not a temporary.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i meant, i have already constructed it, why there is a need for a second construction of the same object ?

Comment: @AntonStafeyev: It's not the "same object". `tmp` is a specific object, which is distinct from the return value object.

Comment: What do you mean, a second construction of the same object? If there are two constructor calls, there are two distinct objects being constructed.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev: "*why it doesn't do it without any optimizations*" ... because elision is an optimization, not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it first move it into another tmp object before actually assigning it to the Greetings object.

Because that's what you told it to do.

Your `operator+` returns a prvalue. Pre-C++17, that means it returns a temporary, which must be initialized by the `return` statement. Since you are returning a variable that denotes an automatic object within the function, that means the temporary will be moved into the temporary. This move could undergo elision, but there's no guarantee of that.

When you assign the prvalue temporary returned from the function, you are assigning it to *an object*. You are not using it to initialize an object; you're assigning it to a live object that has already been constructed. This means that the prvalue temporary must be move-assigned from the temporary into the object you are assigning into. And move-assignment is *never elided*.

That's two move operations, one of them is required.

Post-C++17, returning a prvalue means returning an initializer for an object. The object it initialized will be moved into under the same reasoning as above.

However, you are still assigning the prvalue to a live object. This means that the prvalue must manifest a temporary, which will then be used as the source for the move-assignment. Manifesting a temporary means using the initializer from the function to create a temporary object. And that means move-construction, per the above.

So again, you have two move operations: a potentially elidable move-construction of a temporary, and a never-elidable move-assignment into the live object.

If you had instead done this:

```
    MTX::String tst1 = "Hello World";
    MTX::String tst2 = "! And good bye\n";
    
    MTX::String Greetings = tst1 + tst2;
    std::cout << Greetings.sBuffer();  //Didnt implement ostream stuff yet
```

Then `Greetings` object would be *initialized* by a prvalue, not assigned to by a prvalue. Pre-C++17, both the move from the automatic within the function and the move from the temporary into `Greetings` could be elided. Post-C++17, the move from within the function could still be elided, but there *is no move* from the prvalue. It never manifests a temporary at all; it will be used to directly initialize the `Greetings` object. That is, there is only one move to elide; no second move ever even potentially happens.

The take home lesson is this: avoid creating an object, then initializing it whenever possible. Create and initialize the object in one step.

Comment: So there is no way to cut the double move with this operation except enabling optimizations, is that correct ?

Comment: @AntonStafeyev: Did you read the "If you had instead done this" part? Also, yes, elision is an optimization, not a requirement. If a compiler doesn't want to do it at a particular level of optimizations, that's the compiler's choice, and you have to deal with it.

Comment: Yes i did read, and i tried it before the answer, it is more of "maybe i did smth wrong" and the is a better way of handling it ? i will be mainly working on embedded stuff with it and memory is kinda limited. and that second object that is created doesn't cost free memory :)

Comment: With proper move operations defined, the additional object doesn't do additional allocations, and does essentially "cost free memory", unless you overflow the stack. What concerns me is that your `operator+` reuses `*this` object regardless of whether it will be needed down the road. The proper way to do this optimization would be to define `operator+=` and to overload `operator+` based on rvalue-ness of the lhs. The `const String&` version should allocate and copy, and the `String&&` version should call `operator+=` on the lhs.

Comment: Also, while we are talking move semantics, use `unique_ptr<char[]>` and `make_unique<char[]>` instead of new and embrace the rule of 0. And why don't you use std::string? **Edit:** I see, for the sake of learning. Just make sure to use `std::string` in a real project where you're tight on memory, because SSO can save you lots of allocations.